# On the charateristic function of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

For all random variables that admit a probability density function (PDF), their characteristic function provides an alternative way to completely define its probability distribution.
**Why is that**? The explanation I gave to myself is that the Fourier transform operator $\mathcal{F}$ is unitary on $L^2$, and the PDF as a (Radon-Nikodym) derivate, is unique every time it exists. So for square-integrable PDFs, this makes sense... but generally speaking, the only requirement for a PDF $p(x,t)$ is to be integrable ($L^1$). Who guarantees then that the map $\mathcal{F}[p](k,t)$ uniquely defines an object?

Comment: For **any** random variable the characteristic function completely determines  the distrbution. See Inversion Fromuls in K L Chung's book.

Comment: Yes, I was precisely asking the reason for this fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by the "reason for this fact" ? . Using the characteristic function , you can recover the distribution $\mu$

$$\mu(a,b)+\frac{1}{2}\mu(\{a\})+\frac{1}{2}\mu(\{b\})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}\psi(t)\,dt$$

where $\psi$ is the characteristic function. So knowing $\psi$ uniquely determines the distribution $\mu$.

And it's true for **ALL** random variables and not necessarily for those which has a PDF.

As you can see that we are able to recover the Measure(distribution) itself that the random variable induces on $\Bbb{R}$. This is because if the measure of intervals of the form $(a,b]$ is known (i.e. $\mu(a,b]$ is known) then the measure $\mu$ is uniquely determined due to the Caratheodory Extension Theorem. Alternatively , if $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two Probability Measures agreeing on a $\pi$-system that generates the Borel Sigma algebra  , then due to the Sierpinski-Dynkin $\pi-\lambda$ theorem , $\mu=\nu$ on the Borel Sigma algebra. In this case $\{\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i},b_{i}]\,,a_{i},b_{i}\in\Bbb{R}\,,n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is a $\pi$ system that generates the Borel Sigma Algebra.

For a proof of the Inversion Formula I used see [Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) Theorem $3.3.11$ . Otherwise refer to Theorem $9.5.1$ [Sidney Resnick - A Probability Path](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/9145_2018-9-18-12-59-30.pdf)

Comment: Typo in the formula of the inverse ;)

Comment: @Snoop I forgot the snake. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't clearly figure out the domain of $\mu$ since it can be a function of two inputs $\mu(a,b)$ or a single one $\mu(\{a\})$. Secondly, who tells me the limit you wrote always exists? Third, in order to know a characteristic function, you should know first the random variable $X$ it's referred to, and, hence, its distribution $\mu^X$. So isn't this a circular argument?

Comment: @ric.san Its not a "function" . It's a measure. It's a set function which takes sets as input and outputs it's "volume" or probability. $\mu$ is defined for all Borel sets $A$.  A random variable defines a "distribution" on $\Bbb{R}$ by $\mu(A)=P(X\in A)$ . By  $\mu(a,b)$ I mean $P(X\in(a,b))$ for the open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: @ric.san A characteristic function is defined for a distribution. That is if $X$ is a random variable with distribution $\mu$ . Then the characteristic function is the Fourier transform of the distribution $\mu$. So a definition using random variables is not well defined. Instead, you can if you want , define the characteristic function for a cdf (which completely characterizes a distribution).

Comment: @ric.san A random variable on the other hand is indeed a "function" from a given probability space. So summing up, instead of $\mu(a,b]$ . Using the formula I gave, you can directly calculate the cdf $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,a])$ . That is a theorem due to Levy . In particular you can also get back the pdf(if the random variable has a pdf) by the formula using $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-itx}\psi(x)\,dx$ .

Comment: @ric.san I understand that if you don't know measure theory, then these things might seem alien to you. But the only way to rigourously justify is by using measure theory. If you want just an intuitive answer , then you can take for granted that $f(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-itx}\psi(x)\,dx$ . But if you want a proof, then again refer to the book by Rick Durret in the section I mentioned.

Comment: @ric.san Otherwise refer to the book by Sidney Resnick , A Probability Path.